# PHP file txt upload content validation

Tags: php, file, validation, upload

I wrote a PHP script to upload a *.txt* file and it works partially:

```
<?php
    $allowedExts = array("txt");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    $dest = "/etc/squid/squid.conf";
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "text/plain")
    && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 170000)
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<div style='text-align: center'>";
            echo "Upload File Success!!<br><br>";
            echo "FIle : " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
            echo "Type : " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
            echo "Size : " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
            
            echo "</div>";

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
            "/var/www/squid_proxy/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
            copy("/var/www/squid_proxy/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"],
                $dest);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div style='text-align: center'>";
        echo "Error, File upload only .txt";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Both file type and MIME validation work well, but I want a validation of the file's content. The file is stuctured with headers. See this example:

```
#ADVANCED

#WIZARD
```

Before the file upload to server, it must be checked that the file contains `#ADVANCED` in the first line and `#WIZARD` in the third line.
If the headers are missing or the file is empty, an error message should be shown.

How can I  validate the content of the uploaded file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `$line[0]` is Line 1 and `$line[2]` is line 3. [`file()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) reads entire file into an array.

```
$lines = file($myFile); //file lines into an array

if (strip($lines[0]) == '#ADVANCED' && strip($lines[2]) == '#WIZARD'){
//success
}
```

**EDIT** (as suggested by @barmar)

Added `strip()` to the variable `$lines[0]` and `$lines[2]` to trim the `/n` char.

Comment: You need the flag `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES`, or call `strip($lines[0])` and `strip($lines[2])`.

Comment: @Barmar Is this necessary? If yes, then why?

Comment: By default, each string will end with newline, e.g. `"#ADVANCED\n"`. This won't be equal to the string without newline.

Answer (score 0):

Use `file` function. It will return array of lines of you txt-file.

```
$lines = file($filename);
// Then you can check if 
if ($lines[0] == '#ADVANCED' && $lines[2] == '#WIZARD') {
    // do some stuff
}
```